# Is it possible to write an html form and include with an aspx file?

Tags: html, asp.net

I am trying to abstract the login form from an html page.  Is it possible to have the contents of the form in one file and include the contents into an html page.  I am doing this in asp.net, and I would prefer to put the content of the form in a .aspx or .ascx file.

Currently the only way I can think of doing this would be to use some javascript hack which I would prefer to stay away from.

```
<form id="login">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Sign In</button>
    <small><a href="login/password.aspx">Forgot your password?</a></small>
</form>
```

So I want to take labels and inputs and put them in another file.  Is it possible to include them into this formusing my .aspx file?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're using web forms? Because ASP.Net MVC lets you do whatever you want to the html.

In that case, remember that Web Forms has one special form, that normally looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="theForm" runat="server">
<!-- everything goes in here -->
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The trick is that Web Forms has two rules about this form: it should be the *only* form with the `runat="server"` attribute, and it doesn't like it if you nest another form element *inside* the special form. However, you are perfectly free to include another form element on the page that's *outside* of this form element and does *not* use the `runat="server"` attribute:

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="login" action="...">
   <!-- login stuff goes here -->
</form>
<form id="theForm" runat="server">
   <!-- everything else goes in here -->
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And of course you can use css styles to position that new form however you want on the page, within the limits of css.

That out of the way, you're also talking about moving this code to another file. Specifically, it sounds like you're wanting to use an older `include` directive. Those aren't really considered good practice anymore, but you do have a number of options available. In Web Forms, this could be part of your [Master page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx). In MVC, it might be something like [Partial View (scroll down at the link)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410123(v=vs.100).aspx). Additionally, with Web Forms, you could implement this as a user control, where you don't need the `form` element any more. Instead, you rely on the form from the ASP.Net page, and just supply the server controls and code for the login button.

Comment: Just encountered this... really quite annoying.